# How to consume loacalhost windows service from a website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsp

I am new in this .I have a web page and a windows based service running running on client machines.When client open Web-URL in his browser they need to call windows service .How to integrate ?
Ex-Client open a URL and Web page (JSP page) call client installed windows based service .There are multiple numbers of clients .Please help me on this .

Comment: Hello, you are going to need to be way more specific, show code, etc.

Comment: <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    JSP Page:<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8098/signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: Windows Service Config:<appSettings>    <add key="WebAppEndpoint" value="http://localhost:8098"/>                </appSettings>

Comment: I want to call installed windows service from a website .